# Jquery Tooltip for displaying brief details

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Can anyone suggest good jquery tooltip to show brief details for small part.
i want to show **3-4 lines of details** in tool tip.

Comment: [jQuery Tooltip plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/10-excellent-tooltip-plugins-with-jquery/
- http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of jquery tooltips [here](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/)